# Suggestions for revisions to my social network "Updates" table?

Tags: mysql, database, foreign-keys, relational-database

As I continue to work on my social networking site (which I'll probably never finish), I've decided I probably should revise my "Updates" table. If you think of this like Facebook, the Updates table stores stories for the newsfeed, such as User_123 changed his status, or SomeOtherUser added a new photo/video, or YetAnotherUser joined a group.

My current table structure is as follows:

***UPDATES***

**PK**  Update_ID

Type

Update_Content

**FK** Photo_ID

**FK** Video_ID

**FK** Owner_ID

**FK** Group_Wall_ID

**FK** Friend_Wall_ID

Upvotes

Downvotes

Timestamp

As a note, Type refers to the kind of update it is (1 is a status update, 2 is a user joined a group, 3 is a new photo, etc...) and Update_Content is the status text, or a message like "User_123 joined a group"

Right now the way I have it, when a user posts an update to their own "wall", Group_Wall_ID and Friend_Wall_ID are 0 by default. Whereas if that user posts an update to a Group, Group_Wall_ID has a value and Friend_Wall_ID doesn't.

Also, if the update is only a status update, Photo_ID and Video_ID are 0 by default. However, if the update is a new photo, Photo_ID would have a value that corresponds with a PK in the Photos table.

I feel like the structure of this table is pretty inefficient and can use some revisions. Can anyone suggest any revisions to make this table better? Any feedback would be great! Thanks and Happy Holidays!

Comment: is it a requirement to use a relation database for this?

Comment: @TRENT its not a requirement, but so far I have been using one.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this application is a good fit for MySQL. With MySQL you are pulling all the resources together on every read. It also doesnt seem that a feed will need to span very far back chronologically.

I think a better solution is to push an activity to the appropriate feed on write. So if you post a video, it gets appended to all of your friends news feeds. You could limit each feed to 100 items to keep the lists smaller.

I think using redis would be more appropriate. You could have a list for each user's activity feed. `LPUSH user_id` 'John just added a  <a href="/johnsvideo">video</a>`

This solution requires you to have a lot of memory though, and also it may be problematic if a user deletes something from their feed.

Comment: You're proposing denormalization. The usual warnings apply here.